# Using okhttp Interceptor to check the network connectitivty

Tags: android, okhttp

Could we use **Interceptor**  to check the network connectivity and proceed if only it's connected?

NOTICE: I'm talking about how to use okhttp interceptors to unify the network connectivity checking.

Comment: Did you consider overriding the `OkHttpClient` itself?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `BroadcastReceiver` to make your application be notified when there is a change in internet connectivity.

Manifest:

```
<receiver android:name="com.example.app.ConnectivityChangeReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

The `BroadcastReceiver` itself:

```
public class ConnectivityChangeReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

   @Override
   public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
      if (isOnline(context)) {
         debugIntent(intent, "grokkingandroid");
      }
   }

   private boolean isOnline(Context context) {
      ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
      NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
      return (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnected());
   }

   private void debugIntent(Intent intent, String tag) {
      Log.v(tag, "action: " + intent.getAction());
      Log.v(tag, "component: " + intent.getComponent());
      Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
      if (extras != null) {
         for (String key: extras.keySet()) {
            Log.v(tag, "key [" + key + "]: " +
               extras.get(key));
         }
      }
      else {
         Log.v(tag, "no extras");
      }
   }
}
```

[As in](http://www.grokkingandroid.com/android-getting-notified-of-connectivity-changes/)

[More on `BroadcastReceiver`](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBroadcastReceiver/article.html#broadcastreceiver_implementation)

**Update note:**

> Also, apps targeting Android 7.0 and higher must register the CONNECTIVITY_ACTION broadcast using registerReceiver(BroadcastReceiver, IntentFilter). Declaring a receiver in the manifest doesn't work.

See [the docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html#CONNECTIVITY_ACTION) for other options

Comment: Thanks but you get my question wrong. I'm talking about how to use okhttp interceptors to unify the network connectivity checking.

Comment: maybe you didn't see the okhttp tag.

Comment: Maybe the world would be a better place if everyone was nicer to each other.