# okhttp Interceptors to intercept when internet is disabled

Tags: android, retrofit2, okhttp

I am working on network module where it should provide offline data where I am fetching previously stored JSON response from local db and building response and returning to the application. All this is happening in my `okhttp Interceptor` at application level. I know I could have checked for n/w availability with `ConnectivityManager`

Every time I tried with n/w disabled or changing server false server URL for testing, Debugger just disappears call to `chain.proceed(request)`

Please note I knew I would have landed in `onFaluire` of retrofit in my app for any internet error. but I don't want that. Instead I want that to be handled inside interceptor and build response and return.

Searched on net found one [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28806044/using-okhttp-interceptor-to-check-the-network-connectitivty) similar to this.

Let me know if any clarity needed on this.

Comment: can you provide the code of your interceptor? You might be able to force the response to be a success from within the interceptor itself if that's what you want

Comment: @ValerioSantinelli yes i can do that. i did that also. but that executes only if internet is enabled. incase of internet disabled. code after `chain.proceed(request)` is not executing.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is very old post, but for those like me that also encounter this problem here's what I found.

The `chain.proceed(request)` call will throw an exception so any codes below this call won't be executed.

So if you really want to execute a codes when an exception occurred you may wrap the `chain.proceed()` call with `try-catch`.

```
override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain): Response {
    try {
        val response = chain.proceed(chain.request())
        return response
    } catch (ex : Exception) {
        // handle the exception if you need to
    }
    // your codes here. 
}
```

**Warning**: You'll lose access to the `response` when an `exception` occurred so you need to return an alternative `response` because it's required. And codes below `try-catch` statement won't be executed if there's no `exception` thrown by the `chain.proceed()` call.